# How to query a jsonb in postgres with multiple array objects to fetch results in different columns rather different rows

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

The Question asked may be misleading but please go through the below problem statement. I have the below column **name event_json(of type jsonb)** in table transaction_events. The column has the following record :

```
{
    "moneySender": {
        "moneypaid": [{
            "mobileNumber": "9999999999",
            "userId": "lara"
        }, {
            "mobileNumber": "9999999990",
            "userId": "clark"
        }]
    },
    "serviceChargesPaid": {
        "serviceChargePaid": [{
            "mobileNumber": "9999999999",
            "userId": "balu"
        }, {
            "mobileNumber": "9999999990",
            "userId": "vijay"
        }]
    }
}

select 
moneypaid->'userId' as moneySender,
serviceCharges->'userId' as serviceChargesSender
from test te,
jsonb_array_elements(jsonbcol->'moneySender'->'moneypaid') moneypaid,
jsonb_array_elements(jsonbcol->'serviceChargesPaid'->'serviceChargePaid') serviceCharges
where te.id=3
```

I am getting

| moneySender | serviceChargesSenderheader |
| --- | --- |
| lara | balu |
| lara | vijay |
| clark | balu |
| clark | vijay |

My anticipated result is:

| moneySender | serviceChargesSenderheader |
| --- | --- |
| lara | balu |
| clark | vijay |

Could you please suggest how to get the result I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the results of the two "unnesting" functions by their array index. This can be done by using `with ordinality` to get the array index in the result:

```
select x.sender ->> 'userId' as money_sender,
       x.charges ->> 'userId' as services_charges_sender 
from test te
  cross join lateral (
     select s.sender, p.charges
     from jsonb_array_elements(te.jsonbcol->'moneySender'->'moneypaid') with ordinality as s(sender, idx)
       join jsonb_array_elements(te.jsonbcol->'serviceChargesPaid'->'serviceChargePaid') with ordinality as p(charges, idx) on s.idx = p.idx
  ) as x
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6a1ae4b78eb6f39195ef00427bfd79db)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
I may be wrong in projecting one thing.. Irrespective of no of elements in any array the records should be printed in next column
for eg:If I have 3 elements in moneySender and 1 element(object) in serviceChargesPaid then the result should be like

|moneySender service|ChargesSenderheader|
|lara| |balu
|clark| |null
|some|      |null

Comment: @harsha: you should have included that requirement in your initial question. You can probably get by using a `full join` instead of `join`